# Setting the width of a carousel using html

Tags: html, css, width, carousel

I have tried to reduce the width of my carousel so that it doesn't take up the whole width of the page but it doesn't seem to be working. I would like the width to only span over 8 columns and to be centred. I have tried changing the CSS code so that the width was 50% and not 100% but this did not work.

```css
.item {
  height: 300px;
}

.item,
img {
  height: 500px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.item h3 {
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: cornsilk;
}

.item p {
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: cornsilk;
}
```

```html
<!--Start of carousel-->
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> </li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"> </li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"> </li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/c1.jpg" alt="First slide" />

      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Welcome to my amazing website</h3>
        <p3>Hope you enjoy!</p3>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/c2.jpg" alt="Second slide" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/c3.jpg" alt="Third slide" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you work with the upper level, i.e. with the outer div element (`id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide"`)?

E.g.

```
.carousel{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

With bootstrap you could also use the bootstrap-grid including offsets: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/